# Есть ли в Parsec парсер, принимающий любой символ?

Tags: haskell

Есть ли в Parsec парсер, принимающий любой символ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Посмотрите на [`anyToken`]`[1]` из `Text.Parsec.Combinator` или, если не нужен EOF, то [`anyChar`]`[2]` из `Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Char`.

Markdown-парсер Хэшкода почему-то выдает битые ссылки, даю plaintext'ом:

1. http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/latest/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Combinator.html#v:anyToken
2. http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.1.0/doc/html/Text-ParserCombinators-Parsec-Char.html#v:anyChar

Comment: Благодарствую.